# Convert currency string to float with COP cents

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert: `"121.231.232,99"` into currency format `"121231232.99"` any suggestion?

The following code works really well with almost use cases that I found:

```
values = ["2,000,000.00","1,500.00","10,000,000.00","12,123.00","121,231,232.00","121.231.232,99"]

def parse_money_v2(valor):
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')
    value = locale.atof(value)
    value = round(value,2)
    value = "{:.2f}".format(value)
    return value
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`price_parser`](https://pypi.org/project/price-parser/) module as follows:

```
from price_parser import Price
values = ["2,000,000.00", "1,500.00", "10,000,000.00", "12,123.00", "121,231,232.00", "121.231.232,99"]


def parse_money_v2(valor):
    return Price.fromstring(valor).amount


for i in values:
    print(parse_money_v2(i))
```

**Output:**

```
2000000.00
1500.00
10000000.00
12123.00
121231232.00
121231232.99
```

*Also, try to write all the variable names in the same language, it's a good practice and improves the readability of your code if it's long and will be read by other people.*

Comment: Thanks! Your soluction works with the previous cases mentioned. But trying with `"2.800.00"` returns `None`, Any idea?